# Vertx client gets clientabort exception

Tags: https, vert.x

I am geting clientabort sockettimeout read exception at server side while invoking a rest service through https client inside vertx application. If i invoke a http setvice, it works fine though.

I get 200 ok in vertx and do not get any data back. And also i get connection was closed error in vertx.

Any idea why it happens. Help appreciated.

Code:

```
final HttpClient httpClient1 = vertx.createHttpClient(
    new HttpClientOptions()
    .setDefaultHost("localhost")
    .setDefaultPo‌​rt(8443)
    .setSsl(true‌​)
    .setKeepAlive(true)‌
    ​.setMaxPoolSize(100)‌​
    .setTrustAll(true)
    );
‌​HttpClientRequest req = httpClient1.request(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/test/");
req.headers()
    .set("Content-Length","10000000")‌​
    .set("Content-Type",‌​"application/json")
    .‌​set("Cache-Control", "no-transform, max-age=0");
Buffer body=Buffer.buffer("Hello World");
req.write(body);
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: final HttpClient httpClient1 = vertx.createHttpClient(new HttpClientOptions().setDefaultHost("localhost").setDefaultPort(8443).setSsl(true).setKeepAlive(true).setMaxPoolSize(100).setTrustAll(true));HttpClientRequest req = httpClient1.request(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/test/");req.headers().set("Content-Length","10000000").set("Content-Type","application/json").set("Cache-Control", "no-transform, max-age=0");        Buffer body=Buffer.buffer("Hello World");req.write(body);

Comment: Why do you set `Content-Length` to `10000000`? It must be equal to size of body. Do you call `end` method on your `request`?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way to send a request.
Hope working example may help you.

Server:

```
    final Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler((c) -> {

        c.bodyHandler(b -> {
            System.out.println(b.toString());
        });
        c.response().end("ok");
    }).listen(8443);
```

Client:

```
    final HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient(
            new HttpClientOptions()
                    .setDefaultHost("localhost")
                    .setDefaultPort(8443));


    client.request(HttpMethod.POST, "/", (r) -> {
        System.out.println("Got response");
    }).putHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString("Hello".length()))
             .write("Hello").end();
```

Two important notes: you must end `.request()` with `.end()` and you must set `Content-Length` correctly.